# use already existing table for Confluent JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

according to the examples from confluent docs (https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html) I am trying to get a solution working, where I can reuse my already existing table from a previous legacy system and all messages from a certain topic shall be written via "upset" into it.

So in general based on the example from confluent, how could I write all messages from topic orders into a table called "myOrders" (which is already existing) instead of auto create a new table in my database with the same name as the topic name?

Answer (score 0):

The table can be auto created if it does not exist by setting auto.create to true in the configuration.

However, out of the box, the JDBC Sink Connector can reuse your "myOrders" table.

Please see https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html#auto-creation-and-auto-evoluton

This applies to the current documentation and the Confluent Platform 3.1.1 version you linked.